# PostgreSQL Not Opening the port 5432 on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I bought a VPS from DigitalOcean with applications Rails+Unicorn+Nginx. I installed Postgresql 9.1 and trying to accept remote connections from that. I read all of the solutions/problems about it (Googled much) and did exactly. The problem is the following:

> psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>       Is the server running on host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I edited the postgresql.conf file with  `listen_addresses='*'`
I edited the pg_hba.conf file and added `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`
I restarted postgresql service and even the VPS however still I cannot connected to the database. So I tried to check the server's listening ports:

```
netstat -an | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8356     /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

and then I nmap'ed the server:

```
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
21/tcp  open  ftp
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
554/tcp open  rtsp
```

But still I cannot understand why postgresql not serving at the port 5432 after the configurations. Need advice.

Thanks.

Comment: You nmap-ped from a different machine? Note: by default nmap stops scanning at port 1024, IIRC.

Comment: yes nmap-ped from a different machine. you're right I nmap-ped 5432 and it says: 5432/tcp closed postgresql

Comment: Could there be a firewall inbetween them ?

Comment: in the name of firewall, there is iptables are running on the machine. however when i add the necessary rules to open the port 5432, it's not working.

Comment: Looks like postgres didn't pickup your change to listen_addresses! Netstat output should list 0.0.0.0:5432 not 127.0.0.1:5432. Did you restart postgres after changing the config?

Comment: @Eelke yes I restarted postgresql and the VPS as well. By the way when I run the command "sudo netstat -plunt" it outputs:

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      783/postgres

Comment: You can verify if you changed the right config file by executing the following query when connected to postgres `SHOW config_file;`

Comment: just checked. I edited the right file.